# Need help to understand why the for loop only loops once

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The code I use below is a function that allows me to get data from an API:

```
def get_evt(adresse, id_machine, bucket_size, token, data):

    TO_DATE = datetime.strptime("25/11/2019, 22:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S").timetuple()


    param = {
    "from": int((mktime(TO_DATE) - (60 * 60 * HOUR_DIFF)) * 1000),
    "to": int(mktime(TO_DATE) * 1000),
    "bucketSize": bucket_size,
    "queries": [
        {
            "signal": data,
            "aggregationFunction": "raw",
            "groupBy": {
                "type": "machine",
                "id": id_machine
            }
        }
    ]
}
    liste = []

    resp = requests.post(adresse, headers=token, json=param)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        # This means something went wrong.
        print('ERROR ', resp.status_code, ': ', resp.json()["message"])
        print(resp.json()["message"])
    else:
        signalsData = resp.json()
        for param in range(len(signalsData)):
            values = signalsData[param]['timeseries']
            print(values)
            for value in values:
                timestamp = int(value['time']/bucket_size)
                valeur = value['value']
                return timestamp, valeur
```

However in this code this for loop only loops once:

```
for value in values:
                timestamp = int(value['time']/bucket_size)
                valeur = value['value']
                return timestamp, valeur
```

What I would like to achieve is to somehow get the first and last value of the list "values" but I don't understand why the loop only works once even though values contains multiple values.

Comment: The loop only runs once because you `return` from the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning out of the for loop, therefore after you have looped through all the values: ie

```
for value in values:
                timestamp = int(value['time']/bucket_size)
                valeur = value['value']
return timestamp, valeur
```